# How can I show number of processed file during loading the page in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a following scenario:

1. A user search something by a keyword hitting my database. For example, a keyword "good".
2. My server side code found there's a 100 records on database following that keyword.
3. My server side code does a for loop each retrieved 100 records and do http request to another web API per record. It takes approximately 10~20 seconds per record.
4. The problem is the user has to wait for a long time without knowing how many records he found by the keyword, and don't know how many records were processed / are being processed.

I want to display how many records were found from the keyword "good" (in this case 100 records), and show #of processed records (like: #/100 processed) in real time.

I know there are many answers for showing spinning loading image or progress bar. But I cannot find good answer or a guide to achieve my goal.

I expect the output of "1/100 processed..." while user is waiting.

Comment: you would return the number to the user from the call which made the request, that request would then make a background thread to do the work, if you want to do 1/100 you would need a lot more, you would need away to expose the service which is processing the work. you would then need to periodically check the progress. I think you will find lots of guide on the internet for doing these types of things, Dnt think So is the right place for this.

Comment: since it's a long running task (assuming 10s*100req -> ~17+ minutes), do you store an "search id" or something somewhere? (could be used for a 2nd API endpoint which checks the status)  -  otherwise is SignalR an option in your application? (server-event after each internal request). - also is optimizing the other API possible or out-of-scope? (might remove the need to even do this, and 10-20 seconds sounds high for a text search, unless it's a HUGE amount of data)